# SQL - how to avoid picking up the same row for concurrent connections?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For example, I have a table like this in mySQL:

```
    ID            Used
==========      =========
   1001            0
   1002            0
   1003            1
   1004            1
   1005            0
```

And I have a php file that might be accessed by hundreds of users at the same time in order to get a unique ID to be assigned to these users.

In the PHP, the basic idea is to select a row that Used field is 0 and then assign Used to 1 for that row. The ID for this row is returned.

Does this concept work? If there are many users accessing the database via the PHP at the same time, is there any race condition and how to avoid the PHP to pick up and update the same row (so the same ID is returned to two different users)?

Comment: Use [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) feature instead.

Comment: I am not generating a new row. Reversely, I may also want to make an ID unused by setting Used field from 1 to 0.

Comment: Let's say I have 10,000 rows created already. I am not trying to create new rows.

Comment: It's certainly non-trivial to do this sort of thing.  Most applications will use auto incrementing fields for identifiers simply because it's just that much easier.  There's enough numbers available that you never need to worry about reuse due to exhaustion, and the fact that numbers, once assigned, are never reused means you don't need to worry about cleaning up data.  Orphaned records will never be incorrectly related to new entities.  `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to lock the table might be useful to reserve the row, but I'm not sure how resistant to race conditions it all is.

Comment: probably I simplified my question. The use case for me is not just getting a new ID. I do want to change some field in a row with concurrent connections. For example, these IDs might be a room ID that have created and I want to pick up a room available and set it to be used so others cannot pick up this room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a good start, but I would add one MORE column of either a timestamp, or just a number column acting as like a semaphore token.  Here is how it would work, starting/adjusting from your example data.  Assume the IDs have already been used a certain number of times based on my "LastSeq" column name just to clarify my next point.

```
ID      Used   LastSeq
======  =====  =======
1001    0      24
1002    0      41
1003    1      15
1004    1      52
1005    0      39
```

Each user who is needed an ID, run a query to get AVAILABLE ordered by random so not all users are provided the "available" slots the same IDs in exact same order all the time.

```
select YQT.* 
   from YourQueueTable YQT
   where YQT.Used = 0 
   order by RAND()
```

Simple enough giving you IDs of 1001, 1002 and 1005 and yes, lets assume this is the random order.  So now, you have 10 people to your site and they are all returned 1001 in the first position.  To ensure only one gets the ID, run a test by issuing an UPDATE based on both the ID AND the LASTSEQ the same as it started, such as

IN PHP, create a loop for your available result set from above query...
then run this [sample] update query until you get one ID that actually returns the status that 1 record was successfully updated.

```
Update YourQueueTable
   set Used = 1,
       LastSeq = LastSeq +1
   where ID = 1001
     AND LastSeq = 24
```

If result is 1 record was updated, you are good to use that ID and here is why.  You know the "Used" was 0 and the last sequence of it.  So, if you try to update the status to 1 AND update the lastSeq +1 for the ID you retrieved AND the lastSeq based on when it was retrieved, whoever executes first successfully will now (ex: for ID 1001, Seq 24) will now have the table updated to status = 1 AND lastSeq = 25.

This means that if a second person tries to set = 1 for ID 1001, it will fail because they too had a LastSeq of 24 which will fail the WHERE clause.  This will continue the loop for the user to try the 1002, and then 1005 until one of them clicks for you...

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to work, the first thing you need to do is reserve the row.  You can do this in an update, and the update should be safe -- although the exact semantics depends on whether you use InnoDB or MyISAM.  Because you want locking and transactions, you should be using InnoDB for this work.

You can reserve the row by setting `used` to `1`.  You can also read back the `id` by using a trick with variables:

```
update table t
    set used = if(@id = id, 1, 1)
    where used = 0;
```

You can then read the value you want in `@id`.  This should be safe, because InnoDB supports concurrent transactions and locking, and the updates should be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to run into a race condition between the time you've selected a row where used = 0 and the time you update that row's used value to 1.

One way to get around the race condition is to run the update first

```
$process_id = uniq_id();
//update mytable set Used = '$process_id' where Used = 0 limit 1
//select id from mytable where Used = '$process_id'
//do something
//update mytable set Used = '1' where Used = '$process_id'
```